# How to storage and get token when custom ClientDetailsService?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

[image]

This is my code.

The **clientService** implements **ClientDetailsService** , but not found the token storage.

How to storage and get token when custom(e.g. database) ClientDetailsService?

Answer (score 0):

When we have a custom implementation of `ClientDetailsService`, we essentially override its `loadClientByClientId(..)` method. This method takes `clientId` in parameter i.e. the username of the client. In that custom implementation class, all we need to do is check if the given client name exists in database or not. If it does exist, then load all its data and return the object. This class needs be injected with DAO or Repository's dependency to talk to database.

```
@Override
public ClientDetails loadClientByClientId(final String clientId) throws ClientRegistrationException {
    Objects.requireNonNull(clientId, "Client ID must not be null");

    final com.ex.auth.domain.ClientDetails clientDetails = clientDetailsRepository.findOne(clientId);

    if (clientDetails == null) {
        throw new NoSuchClientException(String.format("Client %s does not exist.", clientId));
    }

    return convertToDmo(clientDetails);
}
```